# ipad app sending image to photo library does not capture background

Tags: xcode, ios5, cgcontext

I have an app that allows writing on a variety of background colors. When I invoke the method to capture the writing to the photo library, I get the writing but without any background color.

I could use some help to figure out why..

I draw the background color simply enough with:

```
drawImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor];
```

drawImage is defined as a `UIImageView`.

I write to drawImage ok:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    savedImage.image = drawImage.image;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and writing to the photo library is done like this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(drawImage.image, self, nil, nil);
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this help from the Apple Dev. Forum, so I thought I would post it here to help others (and for more comments):

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
```

and then

```
-(void)captureToPhotoAlbum {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); 
    // Get image to save
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];

    // Image cropping
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], CGRectMake(0.0f, 70.0f, 768.0f, 768.0f));
    UIImage *img2Save = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    // Request to save the image to camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img2Save, self, nil, nil);

}
```